# Making a "cached" version of `Manipulate[]`?

Tags: performance-tuning, manipulate

I have a function that is a bit too slow for `Manipulate[]`.  Right now I plan to cache outputs outside the manipulation and just have the manipulator select among cached outputs, but I am wondering if some better version of that trick exists.

Basically, I am creating a [CDF](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/02/22/mathematica-qa-series-cdf-embedding-in-a-nutshell/) presentation in which I intend to show the effect of different values for a correlation parameter $\rho$ in Monte Carlo simulations to the audience using `Manipulate[]` to show the resulting sample histograms.  The simulation process is too slow to make for a good user experience as a live function, so one way or another I will have to cache some things.

It seems that if I am clever about writing a `Module` as an argument to `Manipulate` I should be able to make it cache, say, 199 different output sets corresponding to the various % correlations between -0.99 and +0.99.

Comment: How many parameters do you adjust with `Manipulate`?  If it's only one, the minimal effort solution might be just precomputing a number of frames to show and using `ListAnimate`.

Comment: Also, with `Manipulate` it's possible not to update the output before releasing the slider, or updating the output only with "low quality" (actually custom output can be used) while dragging the slider.  This lets you give instant feedback when dragging the slider and a precise result will appear a second or two after you release the slider.  If the simulation is even slower than 1-2 seconds then you really need to cache something.  How the caching is best implemented depends on the details of the problem.  The most general solution (e.g. `ListAnimate`) is not necessarily the best.

Comment: Risking one more comment, one typical way of caching in Mathematica is [memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html), in case you didn't know about it.  There lots of variations on the technique.  E.g. the number of values remembered can be limited.  However, it seems to me that precomputing values is more appropriate for your case than caching them.

Comment: I am planning on only one parameter.  I did indeed use the `ControlActive` to get low-res behavior (as recommended in the "Advanced Tutorial") but as you anticipate it was too slow.  `ListAnimate` is an interesting idea but I rather like having variable values on the scrubber.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following code demonstrates a bit of caching. The initialization code is run only once, because the variable `cached` which is saved in the `Manipulate` remembers the cached state. So when you copy the `Manipulate` into an empty notebook and open this in a fresh session, the cached plots stored in the saved variable `plot` (stored because of the `SaveDefinitions` option) won't be calculated again.

Remove the `cached = True` line and insert a `Print["Init"]` before the `Plot` command to see that `plot` is recalculated when the notebook  containing the `Manipulate` is opened and viewed in a fresh session (without explicitly executing any code).

```
DynamicModule[{cached, plot},
 Manipulate[
  plot[[kx, ky]],
  {kx, 1, 10, 1},
  {ky, 1, 10, 1},
  Initialization :> {
    If[\[Not] TrueQ[cached],
     plot = 
      Table[Plot3D[
        Sin[kx x] Cos[ky y], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}], {kx, 10}, {ky, 10}];
     cached = True
     ]},
  SaveDefinitions -> True,
  SynchronousInitialization -> False
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Exactly the sort of idea I was looking for, thank you.  I'll be interested to see if the saving works in CDF, which I plan to test today.

Comment: As an aside, this works in CDF player (after clicking past a warning) but not in embedded web pages.  I presume this is due to the security restrictions on general functions like `DynamicModule`.

Comment: @BrianB Good to hear that. Perhaps you could try to work without `DynamicModule` it isn't really essential here. I used it to restrict the effects of `SaveDefinition` to localized names, but if you are careful doing without shouldn't cause problems.

Comment: Just wondering.. Whats done here is a kinda brute force (elegant) approach (which works). 

Is there an inbuilt feature to do this? (I am expecting that such "inbuilt" feature could be advantageous over this approach)

Comment: @myaccount_ram If I had known of such a method I would have provided it, of course.